# Android studio keeps setting int[] variable to null

Tags: android, variables, exception, null

I have an int variable with 6 elements. All the time in the code android sets it to null. I even redefined it in the code in debug mode like this

```
if (yeahsort == null) {
    SharedPreferences prefs2 = getSharedPreferences("KARANTÄN", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String savedString = prefs2.getString("string", null);
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(savedString, ",");
    int[] yeahsort = new int[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        yeahsort[i] = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    }
}
```

during the for loop the variable `yeahsort` becomes an `int[]`, but right after it becomes `null` again. Seriously right after the for loop.

So what can I do to fix this?

Comment: You are declaring a new variable with the same name. That one will disappear once you exit the function.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `int[] yeahsort = new int[6]` change it to `yeashsort = new int[6]` here is a lesson on variable scoping http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html